# Viewing Runes? (Font installation)

Tags: fonts, ttf

I wanted to see runes (not only in Libreoffice) but in Chrome too.
For me, I could not see the following Runes: ᛠᚣᚫᛞᛟᛝᛚᛗᛖᛒᛏᛋᛉᛈᛇᛂᛁᚾᚻᚹᚷᚳᚱᚩᚦᚢ
for me, it was boxes (dotted lines), questionmarks, and something on those lines.

> Note: This *might* be a question that already has a well-approved
> answer, my question was not about how to install fonts in general, but
> how to install one specific either font or package (that would enable
> me to view the specific font)

Answer provided below.

I had this problem for years, did not know it was this simple.

Edit: I Also wanted to create a C program, (Related link below) and installing the below package trough apt worked flawlessly.

[Is there a way to print Runes as characters? - At StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401017/is-there-a-way-to-print-runes-as-characters/66401770#66401770)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Junicode font](https://junicode.sourceforge.io/). With `apt`,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install fonts-junicode
```

Comment: And for a bitmap font, GNU Unifont.

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks for the help, really - It was big. :D thanks!